# pyqt5 gui freez while process in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, python-multithreading

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import wget

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(353, 111)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 16, 251, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 10, 75, 31))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 331, 31))
        self.textBrowser.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.NoTextInteraction)
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 353, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.download)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Download"))
        self.textBrowser.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", " Download progress!"))

    def download(self):
        url= self.lineEdit.text()
        print(url)

        while True:
            try:
                wget.download(url)
                break
            except:
                ...

        print(">>> Download completed!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The `while` loop *and* the `wget.download()` function are blocking. Use [QNetworkAccessManager](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your `download` method keeps running as long as the downloads are in progress.

However, since it is a callback connected to the GUI, it is basically called from within the event loop.
So as long as it runs, it *interrupts* the flow of events. Hence the application freezing.

There are basically three solutions;

- Chop the download up into small pieces that can don't interrupt the event loop too long.
- Do the downloading in a separate thread.
- Do the downloading in s separate process.

I gather that qt has specialized classes for all of these, but I'm not familiar with qt.

Comment: Please can you reply how to use threading with this code. Thank you!

Comment: @DARKSOUL There seem to be several different ways of using threads with pyqt5, and I'm not knowledgeable enough about pyqt5 to say which one is best. For myself I tend to stick to `tkinter` because it comes with Python.